# Virtual Machine to start developing with ASP.Net vNext stack

Tags: asp.net-web-api, virtual-machine, asp.net-core

I want to do some proof of concept coding for asp.net 5, but I don't want to put my current dev machine at risk loading all the new tools, and I'd also rather not have to go through the installs for all of it.  Is there a VM box out there that has a standard set of tools used for developing [ASP.Net vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext) applications?  I know about the [azure marketplace](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/virtual-machines/), but I'm not an MSDN subscriber so many of those I don't have access to, and I'd like to just be able to pull down a virtual disk and run it on my local VM host software.

Comment: maybe this will be helpful https://pfelix.wordpress.com/2016/01/01/using-vagrant-to-test-asp-net-5/

Comment: thanks, I do need to check it out on linux as well, but was looking more for a windows VM

Comment: for windows VM you can try this as start point http://dmitry-zaets.github.io/vagrantfile-windows-iis-mssql/ , but you should change/add your own scripts in vagrant, to install and configure environment for asp.net 5

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not a current MSDN subscriber, I would suggest checking out the BizSpark program at BizSpark.com. If approved, you can get a free Ultimate MSDN subscription including free Azure credits.

Initially, you can use a VM for development. Once you're ready to set up your dev environment locally, you can continue to use Azure to deploy your projects into Web Apps on Azure.

Feel free to send me PM if you have more questions about it.